# The digit at the unit place of $(1!-2!+3!-\cdots+25!)^{(1!-2!+3!-\cdots+25!)}$

Tags: factorial

> The digit at the unit place of $(1!-2!+3!-\cdots+25!)^{(1!-2!+3!-\cdots+25!)}$ is
>
> $a)\;0\quad b)\;1\quad c)\;5\quad d)\;9 $

**My attempt:**
I have just tried to simplify the expression $(1!-2!+3!-\cdots+25!)$.

Now,

$(1!-2!+3!-\cdots+25!)=(1!+(3!-2!)+(5!-4!)+\cdots+(25!-24!))\\=1!+2.2!+4.4!+\cdots+24.24!$

But I am stuck here. The problem appears in ISI admission test-2010.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. For $n\geq 5$ we have that $n!$ is divisible by 10. Hence
$$N:=1!-2!+3!-\cdots+25!\equiv 1!-2!+3!-4!\equiv 1 \pmod{10}$$
that is $N$ is an integer with the unit digit equal to $1$. What is the unit digit of $N^N$?

Comment: $\equiv-1$ should be $\equiv1$.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: The unit digit of $N^N$ is $1$.

Comment: Yes! Well done!